# How do I stop Matlab from displaying matrix content on importdata()

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm running a series of scripts that all import data from different matrix files. It seems that displaying the content of the matrix is taking a lot of time. Normally I would do "more on" and just cancel the display after the first page, but I am doing things automatically here, from the command-line version.

Is there a way to stop Matlab from displaying the content of variables when it loads them? Say, a non-verbose/daemon mode? I couldn't find a way to do it when I searched, but I'm sure there must be one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it! The answer is to add a semicolon (;) at the end of the line, for example:

```
m=importdata('matrix.txt');
```

This will prevent it from printing the contents of m.

Comment: Yes, in general, when you don't want to print the output of a Matlab statement, you must terminate the line with a semicolon.  Furthermore, in a script, Matlab will warn you if you do not terminate a line with a semicolon, so you could watch out for those.  Official Matlab documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresvu4.html).